# Do I need to do a PIVOT in this Sql Server 2012 Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm not to sure if i need to do a PIVOT to extract my data into a simple result set. If I do, then how?

**Context.**

Each location can exist in 0<->many counties.
For each location, display the counties in the same result (say .. comma seperated).

**Sample Data**

```
Locations
Id   Name
-------------
 1   Street1
 2   Street2
 3   County1
 4   County2
 5   Neighbourhood12121
 6   Country4

Counties
LocationId CountyId
---------------------
  1          3
  1          4
  2          3
  5          3

eg.
Street1 exists inside County1 and County2
Street2 exists inside County1
Neighbourhood12121 exists inside County1
The rest do not exist in any counties.
```

**Results**

I would love the following results:

```
Id   Name                Counties
-------------------------------------------------
 1   Street1             County1, County2
 2   Street2             County1
 3   County1             NULL
 4   County2             NULL
 5   Neighbourhood12121  County1
 6   Country4            NULL
```

Is this possible with Sql Server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a comma-separated list, I'd just use the `STUFF`-`FOR XML PATH('')` trick:

```
SELECT L.Id, L.Name,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(C.CountyId AS varchar(max)) 
           FROM Counties C 
           WHERE C.LocationId = L.Id 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Counties
FROM Locations L
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8bc4/3)

*Note: You have not provided a table with county names so I have just used the IDs here. I assume you can figure out the rest.*

`PIVOT` would be useful when you want to get *multiple columns* from row-based data, but since you only want a *single column* here, I don't think it will be useful.

Comment: -Perfect- I changed the subquery to include an inner join because it's a relationship table .. and it's got the answers. Ta mate!